# How does reversing the vertices of a singular simplex leading to a possible minus sign, in Proof of theorem 3.11 of Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The theorem is about the commutativity of cup product, on page 119 of Hatcher's Algebraic topology. In the proof, he defined a homomorphism between the singular chain groups as follows.

Write a sigular simplex as $\sigma^n = [v_0,..,v_n]$, and define $\tilde \sigma^n=[v_n,...,v_0]$. The goal is to define a homomorphism sending $\sigma^n$ to $\tilde \sigma^n$.

He mentioned that the reversal of vertices is the product of $n(n+1)/2$ transposition of adjacent vertices, each of which corresponds to a reflection. So, this means that the orientation is reversed $n(n+1)/2$ times. Then he said that

> So to take orientations into account we would expect
> that a sign $\epsilon^n = (−1)^{n(n+1)/2}$ ought to be inserted. Hence we define a homomorphism
> $\rho:C_n \to C_n,\sigma^n\mapsto \epsilon^n\tilde \sigma^n$.

My question: what's the purpose of adding the sign $\epsilon^n$? Couldn't $\sigma^n\mapsto \tilde \sigma^n$ be a homomorphism? He later showed that the induced map on homology $\rho^*$ is chain homotopic to $Id^*$. Is the sign specially chosen for the homotopy? If so, what's the intuition behind this?

Thank you.

Comment: *The page is 210, not 119

Comment: @Alessandro Yes! Sorry I don't know why I wrote 119..

Comment: Of course $\sigma^n\mapsto \tilde \sigma^n$ gives a homomorphism since $C_n(X)$ is a free abelian group with generators $\sigma^n$. But in general a collection a homomorphisms is not a chain map.

Answer (score 1):

Look at page 211, the term $\varepsilon_n$ is needed for $\rho$ to be a chain homomorphism: Assume you've defined $$\rho([v_0,\cdots,v_n])=\varepsilon_n[v_n,\cdots,v_n]$$ Then for $\rho:C_n\rightarrow C_n$ to be a chain homorphism we need $d\rho=\rho d$, which implies the equation $$\varepsilon_n=(-1)^n\varepsilon_{n-1}\Rightarrow \varepsilon_n=(-1)^{n+(n-1)+\cdots+1}\varepsilon_0=(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\varepsilon_0$$clearly you can just take $\varepsilon_0=1$ and that's all.

Comment: So the sign is indeed for getting a chain map, thank you. What he said above on the orientation is just for intuition, right? Do you know what the logic behind this is?

Comment: I think that the thing with the sign is just for intuition, because taking the minus sign means we're considering the simplex with reversed orientation, so each reflection doesn't change the image of $\sigma$ in the target space (for example, reversing a path doesn't change the path in the space), but it does reverse the orientation of the simplex, so we add $-1$ for each reflection

Comment: Thank you! I am clearer now.

Comment: You're welcome.